# Minimum Geometric Set Cover Problem or Minimum Disk Coverage Problem with graphs in networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx, set-theory

I have a unidirectional graph that looks like below. I want to find the [minimum set cover](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.approximation.vertex_cover.min_weighted_vertex_cover.html#networkx.algorithms.approximation.vertex_cover.min_weighted_vertex_cover) in this graph, where the minimum set stands for a subset of its vertices such that for every edge (u, v) of the graph, either ‘u’ or ‘v’ is in vertex cover.

[image]

There is an function module implemented in networkx called [min_weighted_vertex_cover](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.approximation.vertex_cover.min_weighted_vertex_cover.html) which supposedly returns the minimum set, but I think the solutions returned by the functions are not correct. When I use the function on the above graph, it gives the result as the set of vertices as {{0, 1, 2, 4} which is clearly wrong. One of the answers is {3,0,2}, and with this small a graph, I would assume the module would have given a right answer.

I might be wrong in my understanding of the function, and  if that is the case, can someone guide on how I can go about implementing the minimum set cover ?

Comment: In the documentation you've linked it is stated that an approximated algorithm is implemented. If I understood you correctly, you are trying to solve this problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover which is NP complete.